# Element should have been 'select' but was 'li'

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have to select drop down option and its sub options.but getting error while selecting its sub category [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error it looks like *you are passing an `li` element instance to the `Select()` class constructor which expects `select` elements only*.

Since both the `li` and `select` have the same `id` value, you need to additionally check for tag names - e.g. with a CSS selector:

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#cat_1219"));
Select selectInstance = Select(selectElement);
```